# Error:javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.struts.chain.commands.InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url

Tags: struts-1

struts-confi file

```
<!-- ========== Form Bean Definitions ================================== -->
<form-beans>

    <form-bean name="helloWorldForm" type="com.mkyong.common.form.helloWorldForm"/>

</form-beans>

<!-- ========== Action Mapping Definitions ============================= -->
<action-mappings>
    <action name="helloWorldForm" path="/helloWorldForm" type="com.PracticeProgram.common.action.HelloWorldAction" >
        <forward name="success" path="/HelloWorld.jsp" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

URl:http://localhost:8080/PracticeProgram/helloWorldForm.do

Answer (score 0):

Check your case, com.mkyong.common.form.helloWorldForm should be com.mkyong.common.form.HelloWorldForm and com.PracticeProgram.common.action.HelloWorldAction should be com.practiceprogram.common.action.HelloWorldAction

Are you sure this 2 classes exist in your war in WEB-INF/classes with correct package name ?